# deleting only first instance occurring in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, dataframe, text

I have a data-frame that has text in the first column named 'original_column'.
I have successfully been able to pick specific words out of the text column 'original_column' with a list and have them appended to another column and deleted from the original column with the following code:

```
list1 = {’text’ , ‘and’ , ‘example’}

finder = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in x.split() if y in list1]), None)

df['list1'] = df.original_column.apply(finder)

df['original column']=df['original column'].replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df['list1'],value="")
```

I would now like to build on this code by being able to delete ONLY THE FIRST instance of the the specific words in the list from the 'original_column' after appending the listed word to a new column. 
The data-frame currently looks like this:

```
|   original column  |
__________________________
|   text text word   | 
--------------------------
|    and other and   |
```

My current code outputs this:

```
|   original column   | list1
______________________________
|        word         | text
------------------------------
|        other        |  and
```

My desired to output this:

```
|   original column   | list1
_______________________________
|      text word      | text
-------------------------------
|      other and      |  and
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the first pattern occurrence and remove it without removing the text before this first occurrence you may use

```
^(.*?)pattern
```

and replace it with the backreference to the capturing group value, here, **`\1`**.

You may match any of your words in the `list1` list as whole words (with `\b(?:word1|word2|wordN)\b` like pattern) and capture all the text before it with `(?s)^(.*?)` pattern that would match the least amount of any chars from the start of the string.

Use

```
df['original column'] = df['original column'].str.replace(rf"(?s)^(.*?)\b(?:{'|'.join(list1)})\b", r"\1").str.strip()
```

The regex used is

```
(?s)^(.*?)\b(?:text|and|example)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AHCiH7/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - `re.DOTALL` enabled to let `.` match any char including line break chars
- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `\b(?:text|and|example)\b` - a whole word from a list of alphanumeric words (that may also contain an undersocre)

The replacement is `\1`, the backreference to the value captured with the first (and only here) capturing group.